# PHP - Controle de usuários simultâneos?

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema finalizado e funcionando, feito por completo em ASP.

Estou reescrevendo a versão 2.0 dele, e como vou rever ele 100%, resolvi tentar a sorte com o PHP. Um problema surgiu no controle de usuários:

Eu preciso ter o controle de quantos usuários simultâneos estão utilizando o sistema, pois as negociações das mensalidades da utilização estão ligadas à isso.

No ASP o controle era feito através do `ASP Application Object`, que é uma espécie de objeto global acessível por todas as instâncias em execução da aplicação (mais informações sobre ele **[neste link](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_application.asp)**).

Pesquei sobre isso mas não achei nada concreto sobre as melhores formas de fazer isso em PHP, alguém tem alguma experiência com algo do tipo?

Comment: A título de curiosidade, como você identifica com ASP o número de usuários logados? Você usa o Session_Start para contar o número de sessões ativas ou algo assim?

Comment: @RichardDias Basicamente isso. Armazeno em uma Application a SessionID (e algumas outras informações) de cada sessão iniciada.

Comment: http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/510280-contador-de-pessoas-online-em-tempo-real/

Comment: @JeffersonSilva Eu cheguei a ver esse topico já, mas queria tentar alguma solução sem envolver banco de dados como já tenho funcionando em ASP hoje.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sem banco de dados eu faria assim:

```
<?php
$tempoHoras = 6;
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $tempoHoras * 3600); # Tempo em segundos
ini_set('session.save_path', '/caminho/para/suas/sessoes'); # Local do salvamento

//inicia sessao
session_start();


function getUsuariosOnline()
{ 
    $count = 0; 
    $d = dir(session_save_path()) or die("Diretorio invalido.");
    while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) 
    {
        if($entry != '.' && $entry != '..')
        {
            $count++; //Conta a qtde de arquivos dentro do diretorio de sessao
        }
    }
    $d->close();
    return $count;  
} 

$usuarios_online = getUsuariosOnline();
echo $usuarios_online;
?>
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-save-path.php

Comment: O codigo funcionou sem problemas, era mais ou menos isso mesmo que eu queria... Porém, ao testar ele me listou 8 usuários online (sim, conferi e realmente há 8 arquivos no diretório das sessões). Sabes dizer porque isso acontece? Valeu.

Comment: Provavelente sua aplicação esta sem tempo de sessão definido. Ou seja, as sessões não estão expirando após X minutos de inatividade. Você pode setar o tempo de vida de cada sessão usando http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-cache-expire.php

Comment: @DirtyOldMan O Szag-Ot já editou para que a sessão expire - altere para o valor correto/desejado. A resposta está completa. E Jefferson, `session.cache_expire` serve para expirar o cache. Não vai apagar as sessões do servidor - apenas o cache. Dê uma olhada em `session.gc_maxlifetime` conforme editado por Szag-Ot no original.